How do I use a Custom Setting in a Lightning Email Template?
I would like to use a Custom Setting (or Custom Metadata) as a merge field in my Lightning Email Template, but am getting errors with the suggestions I found using Custom Settings when googling. I couldn't find anything suggesting that Custom Metadata can be used as merge fields yet.
I have tried this (I know this way doesn't work in Lightning but because the right way doesn't work either I gave this a go:
 on behalf of {!$Setup.IssuerName__c.Issuer_Name__c}, that 

which gave me this error when trying to save the HTML:
This template doesn’t support SML merge fields. Use the merge field picker to replace merge fields starting with "{!".: HTML Value
and this:
 on behalf of {{{$Setup.IssuerName__c.Issuer_Name__c}}}, that 

The Custom Setting is available:

and has a value:

It doesn't give me an error saving the template, but when I try and use it I get this error:
SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Hmm. The merge field $Setup.IssuerName__c.Issuer_Name__c doesn’t look right. Fix the expression and try again.: []

In Lightning Email Templates we don't have access to custom settings or custom metadata types.
You'll need to use a Visualforce email templates to access global variables.
